# How to get contenthash of emitted assets in webpack plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

Sometimes, for some reason, webpack emits assets with identical content. In the plugin I'm writing now, I need to make sure that the asset content has changed. I'm using `compiler.hooks.done` hook and `stats.compilation.emittedAssets` argument to determine emitted assets. To make sure that asset content has changed, I'm going to use contenthash.

I've read the webpack documentation, but I can't figure out how  to get asset contenthash inside the plugin. Is this even possible? Does webpack calculates contenthash without additional tuning? Or do I have to calculate the asset hash on my own?

Answer (score 0):

For webpack5 it is available in `stats.compilation.assetsInfo`

This is a map of AssetInfo objects that have the contenthash property